Issues Installing TurtleBot3 Simulation Package and Turtlebot3 Packages
I’m trying to load a Turtlebot3 Model in the TurtleBot3 World.
My reference is: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/simulation/
I’m using ROS2 Humble, Ubuntu 22.04.
I installed the Turtlebot3 Packages from: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/#pc-setup

When I run colcon build --symlink-install, I get the following error in the screenshot.

And when I try to launch
$ export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
$ ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py

it doesn’t work.




make sure that gazebo is installed in your system

find out where gazeboConfig.cmake or gazebo-config.cmake file is located, probably: /usr/local/share/gazebo-11/cmake

then export: export gazebo_DIR=/path/to/gazebo

source your bashrc: source ~/.bashrc

verify the env variable: echo $gazebo_DIR



Hello Dragon, I have Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2.
The command $ sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-* from the Turtlebot3 website didn't work so I installed Gazebo-11 from the official website.
The Turtlebot3 website, selecting Humble: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/#pc-setup
I installed Gazebo from here: https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu
I don't see the folder cmake
This is what I see inside the gazebo-11 folder
mypc@mypc:
/usr/share/gazebo-11$ ls
media  models  setup.bash  setup.sh  worlds

Are you using gazebo classic or ignition ?
